# How can i print the key from specific value in dictionary?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def test(self, ctx):
      dict = {'testrole': 'You have test role', 'testrol2': 'You have test role2'}
      for role in ctx.author.roles:
          if role.name in dict:
              await ctx.send(dict[f'{role}'])
          else:
              pass
```

Now it prints just 'you have test role', how can i make it print this way:

testrole - you have test role to print the key too.

I tried with keys() but it didn't work. thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't all that clear, did you mean that it sent the message "you have test role" instead of "print"? Also, you should refrain from using `dict` as a variable name because it's a built-in function. Could you explain more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes i dont use dict as variable name, it is just for here.

Comment: I want to print they key too like:
testrole - you have the test role
testrol2 - you have the test role2

Comment: Try `send(f"{dict[role.name]} {role.name}")`

Comment: `else: pass` is never needed, just leave out the `else:` block entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate the `dict's key`, a  "`-`"  and the `dict's key value`:

```
# You should define your dict in another part of the code
# Also do not use 'dict' as the variable name (as it is a python built-in function's name)
my_roles_dict = {'testrole': 'You have test role', 'testrol2': 'You have test role2'}

@bot.command()                                  # bot = your discord.ext.commands.Bot's variable name
@commands.is_owner()                            # commands = discord.ext.commands module
async def test(self, ctx : commands.Context):
    for role in ctx.author.roles:
        if my_roles_dict.get(role.name):        # dict.get() will return None if there isn't a key with the provided name, which is evaluated as False
            role_value = my_roles_dict[role.name]
            await ctx.send(f'{role.name} - {role_value}')
```

The same code using list comprehension for a more pythonic approach:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def test(self, ctx : commands.Context):
    [await ctx.send(f'{role.name} - {my_roles_dict[role.name]}') for role in ctx.author.roles if my_roles_dict.get(role.name)]
```

And as an improvement, you could consider sending all the "`my_roles_dict`" dictionary objects that met the condition into one message:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def test(self, ctx : commands.Context):
    output_list = [f'{role.name} - {my_roles_dict[role.name]}' for role in ctx.author.roles if my_roles_dict.get(role.name)]
    await ctx.send('\n'.join(output_list))
```